# A question about the coordinate expression of the Weyl tensor

Tags: tensors, conformal-geometry, general-relativity

The Weyl tensor is defined as the traceless component of the curvature tensor.

So should $$W_{abcd}=R_{abcd}-\frac{1}{n^2}g^{pr}g^{qs}R_{pqrs}g_{ac}g_{bd}$$

The coordinate expression, given [here](http://www.thp.uni-koeln.de/gravitation/courses/Wichmann-WeylPresi_v2.pdf) for instance, is very different from this. But I feel that the trace of the above would also be $0$.

Comment: There are two things you want to capture with the definition of $W_{abcd}$.  The first is that it is totally trace-less, in the sense that $g^{ac}W_{abcd}=0$.  The second is that it has the same algebraic symmetries of the Riemannian curvature tensor; i.e. $W_{abcd}=-W_{bacd}=W_{cdab}$ and $W_{abcd}+W_{bcad}+W_{cabd}=0$.  Your expression fails both requirements.

Comment: @JeffreyCase- Thanks for the clarification.